# Syntax Error Missing SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I created a table `"Prices"` with a column named after the current time.  I am trying to enter 679.09 into the `Prices` table where the column name is 1460217349.29.

```
INSERT INTO Prices('1460217349.29') VALUES (678.09);
```

I looked at w3 schools and I think this is the right syntax but I am getting syntax error `missing SELECT`.Any advice?  This seems pretty straight forward.

Edit: It appears that using a decimal number requires a backtick.  I did not ask about backticks but that seems to be the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Naming column like that is bad practice. Anyway wrap column name with backticks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a very curious naming scheme for your columns.  But the correct way to identify the column is to use backticks:

```
INSERT INTO Prices(`1460217349.29`)
    VALUES (678.09);
```

I strongly encourage you to change the name to something that doesn't require escaping.  In fact, a number or time value seems much more like a value in a column than a column name.

EDIT:

The issue with your naming is that the column name includes a period.  That is not allowed unless you escape the name.  In addition, if you removed the period, then it would be a number, and that is not allowed.

Comment: LOL. Your answer is right, of course, but it looks _so wrong_ due to that funny column name. I wonder when people will try to make up columns with backticks in their names.

Comment: This is not strong encouragement.

Comment: Why do I need to use backticks?  Is it because it is a number?  It is not a keyword.  Would it be better to make the column a date string?